# How to install MySQL c++ Driver on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I had a question before because my code didnt work due to no mySQL driver being installed.

now i have downloaded the latest version of mysql and have qt 5.0.1 however the documentation on Qt or anything else i can find is just not right for 5.0.1 its showing all these dir paths that just arent in the 5.0.1 build and i cant find what to do to just install this driver

any help would be really good, im using windows 7 pro btw

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to find where you have installed mysql. I guess it would be somewhere in your `Program Files`. There you will see two directories: `include` and `lib`. If not - than you haven't installed the developer version of mysql. Don't worry, just run mysql installation once again, select updating your current install and be sure to check 'developer-something' in the wizard.

Now let's assume, you did everything right, and you found mysql `include` and `lib` directories. Remember them (we'll need them a bit later). Now you go to your Qt's directory, and find driver's sources somewhere there: `./Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql`.

Now do several steps:

1. Open cmd and proceed to mysql driver's source directory
2. Type `qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/MySQL/include" "LIBS+=C:/MySQL/lib/libmysql.lib" mysql.pro`, where 'C:/MySQL/include' is your path to mysql's include and 'C:/MySQL/lib' is your path to mysql's lib.
3. Type `nmake` (or `make` if you're using mingw)
4. Type `nmake install` (or `make install`)
5. Add your mysql's lib path to your system PATH
6. Reboot

After that, everything should work fine.

Comment: the problem was that the directory just isnt there, i search my Qt folder for mysql and there isnt anything, thanks for the answer but i didnt really need a copy and paste of what i said didnt work in the question

Comment: I don't this mysql would be installed in your Qt's folder. Or haven't you found mysql driver's sources? Mysql and Qt's mysql driver are not the same.

Comment: and qmake just says no such command ...

Comment: ok...... the plugins file containing a folder named mysql does not exist in 5.0.1 so i cant do cd.../.../.../ mysql because there isnt one. i have MySQL downloaded i have qt 5.0.1 its how to build it i cant do because the documentation is out of date

Comment: Two ways of solving this problem: 1. open `mysql.pro` in QtCreator and compile from there. 2. Add path to `qmake` to your system PATH variable. I recommend the second one.

Comment: ... nvm think ill just close this thread

Comment: I got your problem now. Qt 5.0.2 has released - may be it will solve your problem?

Comment: yea thats what im hoping iv just seen that and am downloading now

Answer (score 0):

Just download 5.0.2 because it actually works and has the path that the documentation shows