# Qt C++ library in Android Eclipse project: QSQLITE driver not loaded

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, qt

I've created a Qt dynamic lib that uses Qt SQL to open an SQLite database, but I'm getting this error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers:
```

The DLL was working fine as part of a Qt Android application, however I need to use it through JNI from an existing Java application developed in Eclipse.

This is the shortest example code that reproduces the problem. I load the library from Java and call its `init()` method:

```
System.loadLibrary("plugins_sqldrivers_libqsqlite");
System.loadLibrary("Qt5Sql");
System.loadLibrary("MyQtLib");
MyQtLib.init();
```

And inside the Qt library I just call QSqlDatabase::addDatabase():

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_MyQtLib_foo(JNIEnv *, jclass)
{
    // Manually create a QCoreApplication instance.
    int argc = 1;
    static char arg[] = "";
    static char *arg2 = arg;
    app = new QCoreApplication(argc, &arg2);
    // Try to add an SQLite db connection.
    QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
}
```

Since the error is `QSQLITE driver not loaded`, and the Qt library was working inside a Qt application, I assume that Qt is doing some initialization that I'm missing.

But this didn't remove the error, so it must be something else. Normally, the Qt application will use [QtApplication.java](http://pastebin.com/kvharw3c) and [QtActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/idgk3iU2) to perform some initialization, so they must be doing something more there that I'm not doing.

Comment: might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944120/how-to-install-mysql-c-driver-on-windows

Comment: @AngryDuck Thanks for the link, but I couldn't find anything relevant to my question except the error message is the same. This guy is on Windows instead of Android, and his use-scenario is completely different - he doesn't load a Qt shared library in an existing Eclipse android project. Did you have some specific reason to post the link, i.e. am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I stepped into the Qt sources to see how the SQLITE plugin is loaded (for the desktop build at least).

The relevant function was [QFactoryLoader::update()](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/plugin/qfactoryloader.cpp). In it I noticed that it iterates all the directories in `QCoreApplication::libraryPaths()`:

```
QStringList paths = QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();
for (int i = 0; i < paths.count(); ++i) {
```

If any of them has a sub-directory named "sqldrivers", it goes inside it and tries to load all the dynamic libraries in that sub-directory.

I then printed out the library paths in a test project I ran directly from Qt Creator - `qDebug() << a.libraryPaths();`, and I saw this path -  `/data/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/qt-reserved-files/plugins`. In this directory on my android phone there was a subdirectory named `sqldrivers`, that contained a single file - `libqsqlite.so`.

I then checked the .java files, and indeed `QtActivity::startApp()` adds the library path:

```
boolean bundlingQtLibs = false;
if (m_activityInfo.metaData.containsKey("android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs")
    && m_activityInfo.metaData.getInt("android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs") == 1) {
    localPrefix = getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/";
    pluginsPrefix = localPrefix + "qt-reserved-files/";
    cleanOldCacheIfNecessary(localPrefix, pluginsPrefix);
    extractBundledPluginsAndImports(pluginsPrefix);
    bundlingQtLibs = true;
}
```

The solution then would be to ensure that there is a `sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so` somewhere on the phone, and then add the parent folder of `sqldrivers` to the library path using `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath()`.

Comment: Dude you saved my life. I had the same problem and stayed blocked several days. Your post help me a lot
Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I stayed blocked several days too. At the end I thought if this helps at least one person it's worth posting, considering how much of a blocker this problem was. Why did you wait several days before hitting SO though?

Comment: Because I started reading again and again the qt doc to try understanding the driver deployment part. But after days of reading this did not unblock my situation. I also tried to use sqlite3 in my app but this was also too hard to import in the native part of my app