# Specify where a .so is to be extracted from .apk (i.e. destination path) when installing on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, apk

I have a .so file which [needs to be installed in a subdirectory named sqldrivers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31694394/492336).

So instead of installing it to `/data/app-lib/org.example.qt.untitled/libqslite.so`, I need to install it to `/data/app-lib/org.example.qt.untitled/sqldrivers/libqslite.so`.

I'm using Eclipse with ADT, and when I want to add a native library, I place it in `libs\<ARCH>`, which is `libs\x86` for the emulator.

So I tried placing it in `C:\Workspace\untitled\libs\x86\sqldrivers\libqslite.so`, but it wasn't added to the .apk at all.

How can I specify where the .so file should be extracted from the .apk on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to achieve this is to copy the files from `/data/app-lib` to some other directory on the first run of the app.

So I simply added some code to the beginning of my app to copy the .so file from `/data/app-lib/<app>` to `/data/data/<app>/qt_plugins/sqldrivers` if it doesn't already exist there.

```
File sourceFile = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/libplugins_sqldrivers_libqsqlite.so");
File libPath = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/qt_plugins");
File destinationDir = new File(libPath + "/sqldrivers");
File destinationFile = new File(destinationDir + "/libqsqlite.so");
if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
    destinationDir.mkdirs();
    try {
        copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```