# QSqlDatabase : Driver not loaded Driver not loaded

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, qsqldatabase

I developed a c++ library using qt. In this one I am using QSqlDatabase to query informations from a SQLite database. Notice : my library works fine in a qt desktop application (I am developing on Linux).

Now my next step is to use my libray in an android studio project. For this I compiled my library using the android ndk (this step works fine) but got QSqlDatabase : Driver not loaded Driver not loaded.

This error occurs when I am calling m_database.setDatabaseName(/Database.db);

Thank for your feedback

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all : the driver is not loaded.

In your case, the SQLite database driver is not loaded.

This can be because of :

- you didn't compile the SQLite Qt driver
- the SQLite Qt driver is compiled, but not deployed
- the SQLite Qt driver is deployed, but not found by Qt

Have a look here, in "Troubleshooting" section : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html

I'm not a pro in Android, but documentatin can be easily found :

- https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Qt_5_MySQL_Plugin_for_Android
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html

Search for "sql" and "deploy" in these pages

Comment: I compiled the driver using the ndk. I can found it in the lib folder in the apk. So I think the driver is not found by Qt.
Do you know how I can say to Qt where to looking for finding the driver (in Android)?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved my problem. Qt did not found the driver in the tree folder of the apk (once deployed on a device)

Have a look on this post : [Qt C++ library in Android Eclipse project: QSQLITE driver not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607280/qt-c-library-in-android-eclipse-project-qsqlite-driver-not-loaded)